# For what purpose do French speakers usually use "soit dit"?

Tags: sens, usage

In conversation with my friend, I said jokingly:

> Ce petit lit est bien moelleux, mais j’ai connu plus confortable, **soit dit** sans vouloir te froisser.

If you move the phrase "sans vouloir te froisser" to the beginning of the sentence, you don't need to use "soit dit":

> Sans vouloir te froisser, j’ai connu plus confortable.

But when you add a phrase like "sans vouloir te froisser" as an afterthought, is it better to place "soit dit" in the sense of "d’ailleurs" or "soit dit entre parenthèses"?

I haven't given much thought to the exact function of "soit dit" until now, but I wonder how French speakers consider this phrasing in general? Would you use it to emphasise the *afterthought* aspect?  Or for some other purpose?

Answer (score 2):

***Soit dit*** is a shortcut to *cela soit dit* and introducing here a clause that make the whole sentence close to an apophasis, i.e. you say something that you wouldn't have say in the first place. A literary equivalent of ***soit dit sans vouloir te froisser*** is ***sauf votre respect*** (with all due respect).

You can find *soit dit* in the similar idioms ***soit-dit en passant*** (by the way, incidentally) and ***soit dit entre nous*** (don't tell anyone).